# SSIS FTP Task - File size changes

Tags: ssis, ftp

I would like to transfer a `.txt` file from a local machine (Windows 7 64-bit) to a Linux server.

The connection uses a passive mode and the task is set up with `istransferascii = false`

No matter, if I use variables or not for path destination, I face the same issue.

The task runs correctly and I receive the file into the remotepath but when I open the file, it is incomplete.

How to solve this problem and check if the file is complete?

Answer (score 1):

I think the native SSIS FTP Task is not very useful.

I've used WinSCP successfully at a few sites.  It seems quite reliable and has more functionality (e.g. SFTP, resuming) and much better doco and support.  You can integrate it into SSIS using the Execute Process Task.

My favourite feature is that you can string a series of commands onto the command line - no need to mess with script files.